# send form by clicking enter in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I'm trying to send form by clicking enter in textarea. I'm trying  this:

```
$('.chatMessage').on('keyup', function(e) {
if (e.which == 13 && ! e.shiftKey) {
   $.ajax({
   url: "/index.php",
   type: "post",
   data: $('form').serialize()
   });
  }
});
```

When I click 'enter', it's going to 'if' but form isn't sent.

html:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="/index.php">
                     <textarea  class="chatMessage" name="text" placeholder="Имя клиента"></textarea>
                     <br>
                     <input class="button" type="submit" name="enter" value="Отправить">
                   </form>
```

Comment: I am not seeing success or error  function in the ajax? How do you know form is not "submitting". Are you checking from network tab?

Comment: @user2181397, It doesn't send information to  $_POST array

Comment: try using the development tool of the browser to see if the request is sent or not, and the response status

Comment: it is not sent, because if it was sent on another page I would see the text that i've sent

Comment: You won't see any response on your page. If you want to do that you'll have to use the `success` function. If you want to reload the entire page you can use `submit` instead of AJAX, like this `if (...) { $("#form").submit() }`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've found a mistake:)

Comment: @GustavoAlves I've this solution. It was not here...In another part of code. In general, this works: `$('.chatMessage').on('keyup', function(event) {
                        if (event.which == 13 && ! event.shiftKey) {
                            $(this).closest('form').submit();
                        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all!:) I've found a problem. It was in another part of my code. In general, this works for me:

```
$('.chatMessage').on('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13 && ! event.shiftKey) {
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
 }
```

Comment: If a button type is submit and if you press enter it will by default hit the closest submit button. You issue was you was using both ajax and submit for the form submission.

Comment: In a textarea, hitting enter will create a new line.

Comment: @CatalinaNeshina No problem on using `textarea`. You can handle the key event to make it submit the form, and something else like `Shift+ENTER` to break the line, like you did above.

Comment: I posted a question about it an hour ago :) There is answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818494/ignore-next-line-when-enter-is-pressed