# Ignore next line when enter is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there are any solutions to ignore moving to the next line?
For example, I have a textarea and when I click enter my form is being sent but at the same time a cursor is moved to the next line, that I don't want.

**Edit:** The problem is solved!/Проблема решена!

Comment: Do not use `textarea` then...

Comment: Agree with @Rayon - just use a text-input field.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about input type = "text"

Comment: Sometimes I'm looking for hard ways to get a solution and forget about simple things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want behavior of `textarea`, use `input type='text'` instead.

To prevent <kbd>enter key</kbd> ,

> Attach `keypress` event and [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) if `keyCode` is `13(EnterKey)`

```js
$('#ta').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="ta" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/tkbt7mxb/)

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Comment: @CatalinaNeshina I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Comment: One more question: now I use input text and I have a problem with auto prompts. When I type the same word (for example), I have a prompt below. Is there any ways to remove it or user textarea instead?

Comment: @CatalinaNeshina, What is `prompt` ?

Comment: Like in Google. When you type a query, you have autocomplete below

Comment: Add `autocomplete="off"`... It will disable `autocomplete`

Comment: Thanks :) So much necessary information I've got from You.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute 'autocomplete' in input. See example below